# Flexbox grid 1col 1row 3boxes

Tags: html, css, grid, flexbox

How can I make this grid without creating 2 columns?

[image]

Comment: Show us the code that you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.left {
  width: 66.66%;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}
.right {
  width: 33.33%;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my flex box as you want ..

```css
.vert_flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.hor_flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="hor_flex">
  <div style="flex : 2; height: 300px">width 66.6%</div>
<div class="vert_flex" style="flex : 1; height: 300px">
  <div class="hor_flex" style="flex : 1">width 33.3%</div>
  <div class="hor_flex" style="flex : 1">width 33.3%</div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex makes life super easy..

```
.container {
display:flex;
}

.left {
    flex:2;
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
}
.container_right {display: flex;
                    flex: 1;
                    flex-direction:column}
.right {
    flex:1;
background-color: #456456;
}
```

and the html..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">aaaaaaaaaaaa</div>

    <div class="container_right">
        <div class="right">bbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
        <div class="right">cccccccccccc</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

You just have to think of everything as a container.. everything inside that container can be flexed..

With  Flex you need to avoid defining anything with px if possible. stick with units of

%
vw/vh r
rem/em